# how to create comment tree in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, comments, django-comments

I need a comment system so can reply a comment to any comment

I know how to write models and views and my only problem is showing them in the template

For example, maybe a group of comments are like this:

```
comment
    comment
        comment
        comment
    comment
    comment
        comment
            comment
comment
    comment
```

How can I display this structure in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Comment` model should have a `parent` field which refers to another comment(**self relationship**).
it will be something like this, add it to your `Comment` model:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')
```

now you have your replies and even your replies can be the parent of another comment.
And in your template:

```
{% for replay in comment.replies.all %}
    <p class="info">{{ replay.user }} | {{ replay.date }}</p>
    <li>{{ replay.text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the field names are just examples

Comment: i know that, i just want to know how to display them in template